# How do I get the full stack-trace form the crash reports?

Tags: android, crash-reports

Recently the Google Play Developer console crash reports started to have the stack-traces cut off at the top. How do I get the full stack-trace?[image: cutoff stack-trace]

Comment: what´s missing there? the first two lines points directly to the cause of crash...

Comment: Doesn't contain the actual exception. Part of it is in the crash title. e.g.

`java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'btp `

Comment: I can inspect the html source and get all of the top 2 lines. But that's not very convenient.

Comment: ok, but what are you expecting? You should check these lines in the class, I guess you have not initialized your button..

Comment: It's not this particular bug. What I do is cut and paste the stack trace into a bug reporting system. With it all in the grey box I could easily do that. Now I have to piece it together.

Maybe this isn't a question. Maybe this should be a bug report.

Comment: if you get only biug reports for one device, in your case Galaxy S6, than it´s possibly a bug in that one.

Comment: I'm not asking about this bug. I'm asking about bug reports in general.